# Rendering Table row vertically

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to render a table row vertically:
If i have this code for example

```
<table>
   <tr> 
      <td>row1 - cell1</td>
      <td>row1 - cell2</td>
      <td>row1 - cell3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr> 
      <td>row2 - cell1</td>
      <td>row2 - cell2</td>
      <td>row2 - cell3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr> 
      <td>row3 - cell1</td>
      <td>row3 - cell2</td>
      <td>row3 - cell3</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

This will render a table like this:

```
row1-cell1 | row1-cell2 | row1-cell3
------------------------------------
row2-cell1 | row2-cell2 | row2-cell3
------------------------------------
row3-cell1 | row3-cell2 | row3-cell3
```

What I want is to display it like this

```
row1-cell1 | row2-cell1 | row3-cell1
------------------------------------
row1-cell2 | row2-cell2 | row3-cell2
------------------------------------
row1-cell3 | row2-cell3 | row3-cell3
```

Answer (score 3):

You can acheive this using `display: inline-flex;` and `flex-direction: column;` on the table rows.

```css
tr {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>row1 - cell1</td>
    <td>row1 - cell2</td>
    <td>row1 - cell3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row2 - cell1</td>
    <td>row2 - cell2</td>
    <td>row2 - cell3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row3 - cell1</td>
    <td>row3 - cell2</td>
    <td>row3 - cell3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't think it's correct. Tables should be used only to display data and rows should be horizontal. If you need other table structure maybe you should use `<div>` and style it as a table?

Comment: @JakubMuda I disagree. Consider a comparison of 3 items (rows) based on 50 criteria (columns) pulled from a database as 3 rows. This data will layout much better visually as 3 columns of 50 rows. Using a table tells us that it is tabular data which is more semantically correct than a bunch of divs if the contents will be tabular data. The fact that we sometimes want to reverse the columns and rows in the display doesn't mean we shouldn't use a table.

Comment: You are correct. It's better to use tables to display data, but I am concerned about transforming the table. I will give example from another question - if you want to make a cell or row a link you can't wrap it in `<a>` tag because it's semantically incorrect. Is that similar to changing horizontal to vertical rows? You can do it and it works but should you do it? It's a good question and I am interested in a good solution.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion. If there is a lot of javascript in use on the page, I'd just use a javascript event handler. If there is little to no js involved and I want to be semantically correct, I could add the link inside each td and add a hover effect on the tr. In practice I often develop in vue.js so I would add an @click attribute to the tr instead of a link and then it's obvious in the html but the logic remains in the js. Definitely no single right way there.

Answer (score 1):

```
<table class="vertical-table">
   <tr> 
      <td>row1 - cell1</td>
      <td>row1 - cell2</td>
      <td>row1 - cell3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr> 
      <td>row2 - cell1</td>
      <td>row2 - cell2</td>
      <td>row2 - cell3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr> 
      <td>row3 - cell1</td>
      <td>row3 - cell2</td>
      <td>row3 - cell3</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

CSS Style

```
.vertical-table {
   display: table;
}

.vertical-table tr {
   display: inline-grid;
}

.vertical-table td {
   display: table-cell;
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Output
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an array of objects:

```
function toTable(){
        var html = "<table>";
        for(var i=0; i < array.length; i++){
            var row = Object.keys(array[i]);
            html += "<tr>";
             for(var x=0; x < row.length; x++){
                  html += "<td>" + row[x] + "</td>";
             }
            html += "<tr>";
        }
        html += "</table>";
    }
```